# How to findout the grade using two tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Having two tables as below:
[TABLE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4weY.png)
[TABLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBG9a.png)

I need to findout the Grades of TABLE 1 from table 2 using Mysql

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join with the `>=` and `<=` operators:

```sql
SELECT t1.name, t1.marks, t2.grade
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.marks >= t2.min_mark and t1.marks <= t2.max_mark
```